# Nested Transaction and EJBContext's setRollbackOnly()

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jta, java-ee-7, ejb-3.2

I am reading the Transaction Management of Java EE 7 and I get confused by the concept of nested transaction and the functionality of `EJBContext#setRollbackOnly()`.

Say I have two Session Beans, `Bean1Impl` and `Bean2Impl` and their signatures are:

```
@Stateless 
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class Bean1Impl implements Bean1 {

    @Resource 
    private EJBContext context;

    @TransactionAttribute(REQUIRED)
    public void method1() {
        try {
            //some operations such as persist(), merge() or remove().
        }catch(Throwable th){
            context.setRollbackOnly();
        }
    }
}

@Stateless 
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class Bean2Impl implements Bean2 {

    @Resource 
    private EJBContext context;

    @TransactionAttribute(REQUIRED)
    public void method2() {
        try {
            //some operations such as persist(), merge() or remove().
            //an exception has been thrown
        }catch(Throwable th){
            context.setRollbackOnly();
        }
    }
}
```

As stated in [Java EE 7 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/transactions003.htm#JEETT00793):

> **51.3.1.1 Required Attribute**
>
> If the client is running within a transaction and invokes the enterprise bean's method, the method
>   executes within the client's transaction. If the client is not
>   associated with a transaction, the container starts a new transaction
>   before running the method.
>
> The Required attribute is the implicit transaction attribute for all
>   enterprise bean methods running with container-managed transaction
>   demarcation. You typically do not set the Required attribute unless
>   you need to override another transaction attribute. Because
>   transaction attributes are declarative, you can easily change them
>   later.

In this case I don't need to specify `@TransactionAttribute(REQUIRED)` annotation declaration in the methods `Bean1Impl#method1()` and `Bean2Impl#method2()`. Am I right?

So in the above code the transaction of `Bean2Impl#method2()` would be running within the transaction of `Bean1Impl#method1()`.

Can I consider it as a Nested Transaction?

If there is an `Exception` has been thrown inside the method `Bean2Impl#method2()` which eventually would lead to a call to the method `EJBContext.setRollbackOnly()` from the `catch` block and as expected it should roll back the operations performed within the `try` block of this method. In this case what would happen to the transaction and as well as the `Bean1Impl#method1()`. Would it be rolled back as well? What I mean is:

What would happen if there is a call of `EJBContext.setRollbackOnly()` from `Bean2Impl#method2()` and

- `Bean2Impl#method2()` is called from the method `Bean1Impl#method1()` before any database operation like persist, merge or remove.
- `Bean2Impl#method2()` is called from the method `Bean1Impl#method1()` after any database operation like persist, merge or remove.

And lastly what would happen if the method `Bean2Impl#method2()` get executed successfully but `EJBContext.setRollbackOnly()` is called from `Bean1Impl#method1()` after successful return of `Bean2Impl#method2()`?

Comment: It's likely to be distributed transaction - not nested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add to @Philippe Marshall's correct answer and your comment - `REQUIRES_NEW` will create a new transaction, independent from the first one. They are not nested. The first transaction is suspended while the second is active. Once the second transaction commits, the first one is resumed.

You do not have to `setRollbackOnly()` manually. Most `PersistenceException`s will do that if needed. You will gain nothing by rolling back transactions that you don't have to. For example, when querying data, you may get a `NoResultException` or a `NonUniqueResultException`. They do not cause a transaction to be rolled back as there is no risk of inconsistencies between the persistence context and the DB.

You do not need to specify neither `@TransactionAttribute(REQUIRED)` nor `@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)`- both are the default settings.

EDIT: to answer your further questions:

I am assuming `@TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW)` on `method2` and therefore two separate transactions.

If there is an `Exception` that leads to the rollback of the transaction in `method2`, the transaction from `method1` will not be rolled back if the Exception is caught. If the `Exception` is not caught, both transactions will be rolled back.

When setting the rollback flag on a transaction, it does not matter whether it happens before or after DB operations, since the entire transaction is rolled back.

Once `method2` returns, it's transaction is committed. Rolling back or committing the transaction from `method1` afterwards has no influence on the results of the first transaction.

A general advice - do not catch `Throwable` - it is much too broad and you might swallow exceptions which you would rather let propagate to the surface.

Answer (score 5):

This is not nested transactions, JavaEE / JTA does not support nested transaction. If `#method2()` is called from `#method1()` it runs in the same transaction. If you want to have a different transaction you need `#REQUIRES_NEW`. `EJBContext.setRollbackOnly()` only works on the current transaction. Note there is a chance that after calling `EJBContext.setRollbackOnly()` all operations on the transactional resource including reads will throw an exception (JBoss AS 5.1 did this, don't know the current behaviour).

**Update:**

```
    }catch(Throwable th){
        context.setRollbackOnly();
    }
```

You don't need this for runtime exceptions, this is the default behaviour of EJBs.

Comment: What I understand from your answer that calling `REQUIRES_NEW` will create Nested Transaction. And I don't need to have any kind exception handling mechanism to handle `RuntimeException`.

Comment: `REQUIRES_NEW` creates an independent transaction

Comment: The right word that @TapasBose looking for is "suspended". Nested transactions are not supported in JTA as of today. Your first transaction is suspended and second transaction is activated, when the second transaction completes (somehow), the first transaction is resumed. See EJB Spec Chapter 8 - Transactions.